# CDI @ApplicationScoped bean in Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a CDI bean that is annotated with @ApplicationScoped. Is there a way to tell Spring to pick it up during component scan, as if it were annotated with @Component? Spring does understand the @Inject annotation so why not @ApplicationScoped?

The idea is that it would be handy to use CDI beans in Spring (at least if they only use plain dependency injection without the fancy CDI stuff like interceptors, decorators...)

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear how is your code structured, if possible just annotate it with `@Component` as well. A component bean in Spring has similar properties as an application scoped bean. The default scope of a bean in Spring is [singleton](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes) and it can be proxied, similar to what `@ApplicationScoped` would offer.

> Spring does understand the @Inject annotation so why not @ApplicationScoped?

Spring offers support for [JSR 330](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-standard-annotations) annotation, `@ApplicationScoped` is nor part of those.